# Is Owin old tech for Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I suddenly found the newest info published date is Dec 17, 2018 about Owin for Asp.Net Core on google page

Question A: is Owin old tech?

Question B: Is there stable JWT libraries?

Thank you ahead.

Comment: emmm,  Microsoft style is frequent change, so I post this.

Comment: Please post different questions for different, well, questions. Whether Owin is still supported is one question - the latest [Owin package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin/) came out 9 days ago and the releases match the .NET Core releases. Where did `Dec 17, 2018` come from? Whether there are any stable JWT libriaries - define `stable` in a web context. If 10 months is `old`, what is `stable`? If the *actual* question is how to use JWT in .NET Core, you'll find a lot of duplicate questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question A: is Owin old tech?

This is subjective but the [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin/) is still maintained.

> Question B: Is there stable JWT libraries?

Yes, there is the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` package for dotnet core 3, you can also find an updated list of some libraries that provide a bit more infrastructure around jwt [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/authentication/community?view=aspnetcore-3.0).